# TUpDown and TEdit with custom captions

Tags: delphi, updown

I associated a TEdit to a TUpDown. It updates the TEdit text fine automatically with the TUpDown.position value. But I want to display custom captions depending on the TUpDown.position value.
For this I unassociated the TEdit from the TUpDown and wrote custom onClick/onChanging handlers. But both of the cases the TUpDown.position contains the previous value (not the incremented/decremented one). What event should I use to update the TEdit.text depending on the right TUpDown.position value?

I use Delphi XE4.

Comment: Did you look at the events for the TUpDown (on the Object Inspector's Events tab)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `OnChangingEx` event. It has a `NewValue` parameter, that holds the new value to which the control is changing.

```
procedure TForm19.UpDown1ChangingEx(Sender: TObject; var AllowChange: Boolean;
  NewValue: Integer; Direction: TUpDownDirection);
begin
  Edit2.Text := IntToStr(NewValue);
end;
```

Comment: Yes there it is. I thought it is a depricated onChanging event handler. The Ex postfix used to be mark this state. :( But it works fine now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @User007: Um, no. The Ex postfix means it's a **newer**, extended version of the event, not deprecated. See `ShellExecute` and `ShellExecuteEx` in the WinAPI, for instance.